# Cocos2d on iPad at native res and not inside box

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

So I can't seem to get my cocos2D app to run at native resolution on the iPad. All it does it run in the little box as if it's an iphone application. I have the latest version of cocos2D inside my app and used the templates to create the project.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: SDK = 3.2 and just the default iPad iOS in the latest XCode release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may wanna take a look in this ,http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the "Targeted Device Family" in the build settings for your project to "iPad Family."